# Search filename for keyword and batch rename files with said keyword

Tags: command-line, filenames, batch-processing, file-rename, batch-rename

I would like to run a command to batch rename files that only have specific keywords at the start of the filename. I currently have a script that batch renames files in a folder and deletes anything in the filename that comes before the second underscore as the starting sequence of the filename is always the same (except for the time & date stamp that changes).

- Image_2022-06-09-12-29-00_Filename-01
- Image_2022-07-09-13-29-59_Filename-02_A
- Image_2022-02-11-09-26-31_Filename-03_02

I would like them to turn into:

- Filename-01
- Filename-02_A
- Filename-03_02

The files will always start with 'Image_', so I am trying to have a search function that isolates files with this keyword, and run the batch renaming script only on those files. The reason for this is sometimes new files (with the starting sequence) are added to the folder after some files have already been renamed (without the starting sequence), which then means the script can affect the already renamed files also.

The current command looks like this (thanks to the assistance and guidance @Aacini)

```
@echo off

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B *.png *.jpg') do for /F "tokens=2* delims=_" %%e in ("%%a") do ren %%a %%f
```

Previously I was using a series of Powershell commands:

```
set current_dir=%cd%
powershell -Command "get-childitem *.png | rename-item -newname { [string]($_.name).substring(26) }"
powershell -Command "get-childitem *.jpg | rename-item -newname { [string]($_.name).substring(26) }"
```

Both get the job done, but again - only when the files in the folder are the original files, not a combination of the two. Any assistance, suggestions, or guidance on where to start would be great!

Thank you very much in advance for any thoughts on the matter!

And apologies if any of this doesn't make sense - this is all quite foreign to me.